# puppeteer-sharp GoToAsync never resolved

Tags: puppeteer-sharp

```
var navigation = new NavigationOptions {
Timeout = 0,WaitUntil = new [] { 
WaitUntilNavigation.Networkidle2 }
 };
    await _page.GoToAsync(Url, navigation);
```

I'm trying to test Angular SPA using puppeteer-sharp, but GoToAsync never resolves. Any help appreciated

Comment: Please provide more details and more code. For example: how do you check if it resolves or not?

Comment: when i debug in visual studio, I can observe that and no log statements printed after.

Comment: Noticed something similar, but in my case, it just hangs on GoToAsync and eventually times out. If I pass a timeout value of 0 (= no timeout) then it eventually comes through after more than a minute. Restarting the app pool always seems to do the trick because next time it seems to work. No idea what is causing it.